# SASS list variable default value

Tags: css, sass

I have the following list in SASS and some classes:

```
$list: 10px, 15px, 20px

.class1: nth($list, 1)
.class2: nth($list, 2)
.class3: nth($list, 3)
```

Is there any to make a default value for the list, so if I don't show 3 different values, the `nth($list, 3)` doesn't return an error and assigns a default value instead?

Answer (score 0):

index() wasn't working for me cause it needs the value as second parameter.
I would recommend using a function as getter for the list values like:

```
$list: 10px, 15px, 20px;

@function getListEntry ($list, $index) {
  @if length($list) >= $index { 
    @return nth($list, $index); 
  };
  @return 0px;
}

.class1{
  margin: getListEntry($list, 1)
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/10a9c8ec389d2229bce5)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Index](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#index-instance_method) and [if](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_8) functions of sass to check if the index exists in the list.

For example, if you set the default value with 2:

```
$value: index($list,4);
@if $value == null {
  $value: 2;
} @else {
  $value : nth($list, $value);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Regards.